# how to save all terms in Fibonacci sequence till `n`

Tags: r, fibonacci

I was trying to save all items in Fibonacci sequence till a given number `n`. For example, if the function is `fib`, my expected out would be

- `1 1 2` for `fib(3)`
- `1 1 2 3 5` for `fib(5)`
- `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21` for `fib(8)`

so on and so forth.

My code is

```
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n<= 2) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(f(n-1)+f(n-2))
  }
}
```

but it only gives a single value for the `n`-th elements in the Fibonacci sequence.

Any clue to save the elements from `1` to `n` as the output of `fib(n)`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of ways to make it:

- **Approach 1:** Redefine `fib` in a recursive manner

```
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n<=2) return(rep(1,n))
  c(u <- Recall(n-1),sum(tail(u,2)))
}
```

such that

```
> fib(10)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55

> fib(20)
 [1]    1    1    2    3    5    8   13   21   34   55   89
[12]  144  233  377  610  987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```

- **Approach 2:** Use your `fib` but with `sapply`

```
fib1 <- function(n) sapply(seq(n),fib)
```

such that

```
> fib1(10)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55

> fib1(20)
 [1]    1    1    2    3    5    8   13   21   34   55   89
[12]  144  233  377  610  987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```

- **Approach 3:** Use `for` loop (*I think this would be the most efficient one among three approaches*)

```
fib2 <- function(n) {
  r <- rep(1,n)
  if (n>=3) {
    for (k in 3:n) {
      r[k] <- sum(r[k-(1:2)])
    }
  }
  r
}
```

such that

```
> fib2(10)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55

> fib2(20)
 [1]    1    1    2    3    5    8   13   21   34   55   89
[12]  144  233  377  610  987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```

Comment: This is a thorough answer, +1 but I would caution that #2 is wastefully expensive.  A benchmark would make an even more thorough answer.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yes, I agree that `fib2` is not a smart one. I personally prefer the `for` loop

Comment: Thank you very much, your anser is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as a recursion, you need to append each item to the front of the list (depending on the order you want the elements in.

You could also do this as a for loop and then the indexing would be more straightforward.  You could use the function you already wrote, but it would be inefficient.  It would be faster to access the i-1 and i-2 elements of your array to calculate the ith element.

Right now you're not storing the preceding elements anywhere.